# Tomcat listenerStart error

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, spring-mvc

When trying to deploy my WAR-file, tomcat gives me the follow errorlog:

```
2011-jan-24 13:16:04 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2011-jan-24 13:16:04 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
2011-jan-24 13:19:09 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
2011-jan-24 13:19:09 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
2011-jan-24 13:19:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2011-jan-24 13:19:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
2011-jan-24 13:21:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
ALLVARLIG: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1488)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4458)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5004)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:4999)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2011-jan-24 13:21:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
ALLVARLIG: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
2011-jan-24 13:24:22 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
2011-jan-24 13:24:22 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

this is my web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>HSR-backend</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispacherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HSR-backend</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Exception is of ClassNotFound. Check for all implemented classes. It says com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener class is not found. Check for its availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to put the [JSF-RI](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) jars in your `/WEB-INF/lib/`